# CSS circle rotate animation causing wobbling(shaking) in IE11 browser

Tags: javascript, html

Image: [Spinner rotating along the border rim of other solid circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weJMQ.png)

Visit https://codepen.io/bygrace1986/pen/wmyarb

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-circle">
<div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .outer-circle{
      width:330px;
      height:330px;
      border:30px solid #001b33;
      position:absolute;
      top:0; bottom:0; left:0;right:0;
      margin:auto;
      border-radius:50%; 
    }

    .spinner {
        animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 360px;
        width: 360px;
        position: relative;
      left: -15px;
      top: -15px;
    }

    .spinner:before,
    .spinner:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
    }

    .spinner:before {
        border-radius: 50%;
        background:
            linear-gradient(0deg,   hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.9) 100%)   0%   0%,
            linear-gradient(90deg,  hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.9)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6) 100%) 100%   0%,
            linear-gradient(180deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.3) 100%) 100% 100%,
            linear-gradient(360deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.3)  0%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0  ) 100%)   0% 100%
        ;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 50% 50%;
        top: -1px;
        bottom: -1px;
        left: -1px;
        right: -1px;
    }

    .spinner:after {
        background: white;
      border: 15px solid #001b33;
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 3%;
        bottom: 3%;
        left: 3%;
        right: 3%;
    }

    @keyframes rotate {
        from { transform: rotate(0deg);   }
        to   { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
```

The inner spinner circle is wobbling(shaking) in IE 11 browser. It works perfectly in Google chrome. Have to test in IE browser only to look at the issue. Appreciate any suggestion/help here...........................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Does it still do it if you apply body { overflow: hidden } to the css?

Comment: @digout yes, even after applying {overflow:hidden} to body also, the same issue.

Comment: Difficult to test but try replacing your .spinner:after with .spinner:after {
 background: white;
  border: 15px solid #001b33;
 border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
 top: 15px;
 left: 15px;
}

Comment: @digout I tried your solution, but it is not preventing wobbling(shaking) of rotating spinner. I think, rotate animation is having some issue with Internet Explorer.

Comment: @digout  I created one pen with my solution in 'codepen' website. Visit: https://codepen.io/sadashivjp/pen/oqqzwg                                                                Open it in IE11 browser, you will be able to see the inner rotating spinner shaking. You can modify the CSS/HTML, in whatever you want, and if it works without wobbling, then you can post the solution here. Appreciate your help here!!

Comment: @digout One more thing here. I need the motion progress front part as somewhat half moon shaped or cylindrical bottom shaped as in the uploaded image. I attached an image at the beginning of the post. If you closely observe, that white inner spinner is bit half-moon shaped at the leading edge. How can we give such an effect to the spinner? Appreciate your help here. I created one pen here: codepen.io/sadashivjp/pen/oqqzwg You are free to do any changes and post the solution here